# Websocket server on C# console application

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm looking for a way to create a console application in c# that acts as websockets server.

I've found that I can include and use SignalR, but it seems that unless you run your app on IIS 8+ it will not support websockets but revert down to longpolling.

I've seen projects like: http://supersocket.codeplex.com/ but the last update to that is about two years ago, it seems dead.

Any and all thoughts are welcome!

Comment: Have you tried fleck websockets?

Comment: I have a small sample with WebSocketListener : https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocketListener-Echo-Server-Example